# What happens to a $\chi^2_n / n$ random variable as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have read that $\chi_n^2 / n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Is this true? If so how could I go about proving it?

Comment: I have a feeling that using the MGF might be the way to do this one.

Comment: In fact, having just done it, it's really easy that way.

Comment: Perhaps the strong law of large numbers could help as well.

Comment: @binkyhorse That's probably easier still.

Comment: @Glen_b Along the same lines, a slightly more elementary demonstration is that since the mean is $1$ and the variance is $2/\sqrt{n}$, Chebyshev's Inequality immediately implies convergence in probability to $1$.

Comment: It looks like urx is spoilt for choice here.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Z_i$ denote independent standard normal random variables, $Y_i = Z_i^2$,
and note that a $\chi_{_n}^2$ random variable is just $\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$, and thus $\chi_{_n}^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$
behaves just like the sample mean of $n$ i.i.d. samples from a 
(non-normal) distribution
with finite mean and finite variance. Now apply your favorite result
about the convergence properties of the sample mean, preferably not one 
that applies
only when the distribution is normal, to this sample mean.